# Can you be co-advised by 2 other faculty instead of 1 for PhD

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, advisor, statement-of-purpose

My primary research interest is in computer vision and deep learning so I will be applying to the CS department. But I also want to be co-advised by a prof who is in the radiology department and work with another prof who is part of the physics department (High energy physics).

Is that a allowed. And if yes, does that seem feasible, or "look good" on the statement of purpose during the application?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the pros and cons of being co-supervised?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/41915/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-being-co-supervised)

Comment: Whether it's allowed or not depends entirely on the rules of the individual institution. As for whether it looks good, that probably depends on how well you explain your motivations for the choice. Personally, I don't immediately see the connection between deep learning, radiology and high energy physics.

Comment: If everyone, including the university/department allow it, then it is fine. Informal relationships are also possible, of course.

Comment: My daughter had two PhD advisors in biology at Berkeley.

Comment: @astronat Deep learning and radiology sounds like cancer or other diagnostics; not sure where the high energy physics comes in unless they'd like to be deep in the weeds in MR physics or something as part of improving their DL models.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions. @AnonymousPhysicist that exactly doesn't answer my questions because that is only in the case of 2 and not 3, but thank you, few points really helped me there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup.
I know it’s quite common in Israel (and I know of someone else who has two advisors). No idea about the US though.
I personally think this should be more widespread- with the way research is going these days, most impactful work span multiple domains and it’s not possible for a single professor/lab-Group to develop expertise in all these domains.
So multiple advisors bringing their expertise is a win-win for everyone involved!